# DDD: Object Id must be 0 before inserting in database

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I am trying to learn DDD, and i am making a simple demo project.

Right now, i have a generic repository

```
public class Repository<T> where T : class, IAggregateRoot
{
    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        ObjectSet.AddObject(entity);
    }
}
```

and a `Product` class

```
public class Product : IAggregateRoot
{
    private Guid _id = Guid.Empty;
    public Guid Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        private set { _id = value; }
    }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    protected Product() { }
    public Product(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

The idea is that i want that a Product which has been created to have an empty Guid. It should get a new Guid only when is inserted into databse.

```
Product product = new Product("Hello World");
product.Id == Guid.Empty; // True
```

How is right now, when i call the repository to insert a product, it inserts it in database with an empty Guid.

```
var repository = new Repository<Product>();
repository.Add(product);
```

Where should i put the Guid generation of the Product? In the repository? If yes, how should i do it, because i have a generic repository.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can change the IAggregateRoot definition to add an ID property, like this

```
interface IAggregateRoot
{
    Guid Id { get; set;}
}
```

as every class of your project will have an id and will implement the IAggregateRoot interface, you can initialize the id inside the class constructor, like this:

```
public class Product : IAggregateRoot
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }


    protected Product() { }
    public Product(string name)
    {
        Id = Guid.Empty;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

and inside the repository Add method, you can put the Guid.NewGuid(), and then pass it forward

```
public class Repository<T> where T : class, IAggregateRoot
{
    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        entity.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        ObjectSet.AddObject(entity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you want the database to create the Guid as opposed to the object creating it? I think the easiest solution would be to set the property to Guid.NewGuid(). If you really want the table to do the work though you may be able to make it nullable in your object and set the default value of the column in your table to newid().

Comment: I've seen an example (requirement) on a tutorial that a Product should have id = 0 before is persisted, just to make this more clear